# Grails needs WEB-INF/tld/fmt.tld in Jetty Production mode

Tags: grails, jetty

I don't know why I'm getting this wired error, I use command `grails prod war` and deploy to a standalone jetty. After started jetty I got this wired error.

```
2011-08-08 12:07:22.898:WARN::Unable to parse TLD: file:/private/var/folders/KU/KUY52WxPExK-Pljd3M-eV++++TM/-Tmp-/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-ROOT.war-_-any-/webapp/WEB-INF/tld/fmt.tld
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /private/var/folders/KU/KUY52WxPExK-Pljd3M-eV++++TM/-Tmp-/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-ROOT.war-_-any-/webapp/WEB-INF/tld/fmt.tld (No such file or directory)
```

which I've neved had that file before, but it runs fine in just `grails run-app`

Thanks.

Comment: I've found this. http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7802

Answer (score 0):

remove this taglib from web.xml

`<taglib>
   <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt</taglib-uri>
   <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/fmt.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>`